# C# Google Drive Connections to 3rd Parties

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

We have a C# service / ASP.NET combo that we need to upload files to Google Drive periodically.
The design would be to setup who we want to connect to in the ASP.NET project then allow the service the upload files.

I have started the project, downloaded all of the libs with nuget, setup my clientid and secret in google and that all seems straight forward BUT my questions concern me connecting to someone else's google drive instance?

I know we need to connect to the drive api and get a token BUT if we want to connect to "johnny customers" google drive instance … how do we initiate that in the C#?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, if they give you an API key you should be able to hook into their Drive as long as the permissions are set correctly. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/6105699?hl=en

Comment: Hey @BitWiseByteDumb, which kind of Drive Instance is "johnny customers"? Is it a personal drive of an account that you have, or is it a [Shared Drive](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310351?hl=en)? Cheers

Comment: Would be a shared drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access your **shared drive** from your C# application, you can use service accounts. The idea of this feature is to have an account that you can programmatically log into and issue requests from it, without needing to explicitly allow the application as you would using a "normal" OAuth2 flow. You can learn more on how to use and create service accounts [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Example C# code using a Service account:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Plus.v1;
using Google.Apis.Plus.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace Google.Apis.Samples.PlusServiceAccount
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This sample demonstrates the simplest use case for a Service Account service.
    /// The certificate needs to be downloaded from the Google API Console
    /// <see cref="https://console.developers.google.com/">
    ///   "Create another client ID..." -> "Service Account" -> Download the certificate,
    ///   rename it as "key.p12" and add it to the project. Don't forget to change the Build action
    ///   to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer".
    /// </summary>
    public class Program
    {
        // A known public activity.
        private static String ACTIVITY_ID = "z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plus API - Service Account");
            Console.WriteLine("==========================");

            String serviceAccountEmail = "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.
            var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Plus API Sample",
            });

            Activity activity = service.Activities.Get(ACTIVITY_ID).Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("  Activity: " + activity.Object.Content);
            Console.WriteLine("  Video: " + activity.Object.Attachments[0].Url);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

After obtaining the credentials and creating the `DriveService` instance, you simply need to call the [`Files: create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) endpoint specifying as parents of the created file (see the ["Request body"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#request-body) spec) the root of the Shared drive, or a folder within the shared drive.

As an example:

```cs
var fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.Name = "My File";
fileMetadata.Parents = new List<string> { "YOUR_SHARED_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID" };


FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("your_folder/your_file",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    request = driveService.Files.Create(
        fileMetadata, stream);
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
}
var file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

#### Reference

You can learn more about service accounts here:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account